# Why GeoPandas clip is so long

Tags: python, polygon, clip, geopandas

I have an issue with `geopandas.clip` that I think it's so slow.
In input I have a rectangular polygon (bounding box more or less around alaska) in a geodataframes and 3 other geodataframe with frontiers from different sources.
My goal is to have the more "large" boundaries in my bounding box.

1. I openned the 3 shapefiles with bbox option to limit entities in my geodataframes
2. I regrouped all boundaries in 1 geodataframe
3. I would like to clip boundaries with my rectangle, but it takes too many time...
4. I will make an unary union of boundaries that remain

```
dc = gpd.read_file(dc_path)

dc_bb = dc.unary_union.envelope

dc_bb_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(dc_bb)).set_geometry(0)
dc_bb_gdf = dc_bb_gdf.set_crs(4326)

gshhs = gpd.read_file(gshhs_path, bbox=dc_bb)
monde = gpd.read_file(monde_path, bbox=dc_bb)
world = gpd.read_file(world_path, bbox=dc_bb)

joined = world.geometry.append(monde.geometry)
joined = joined.geometry.append(gshhs.geometry)

sl_all = gpd.GeoDataFrame(joined).set_geometry(0).reset_index()

sl = gpd.clip(sl_all, dc_bb_gdf)
```

I already tried Rtree and overlay without succes .

Is somebody has an idea to speed up this treatment ?

Comment: What if you try with `query_bulk()` see: https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.sindex.html#geopandas-geoseries-sindex

Comment: Weird, it returns ```TypeError: Got `geometry` of type `<class 'str'>`, `geometry` must be a shapely geometry.```

Comment: You may want to use spatial index : https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/